# How to encrypt an USB stick?

Tags: usb, security, encryption, usb-flash-drive, privacy

When storing personal data on a USB stick, data needs to be encrypted to ensure privacy. Regrettably, this is far from easy to do without introducing a lot of overhead; ideally, the whole encryption process should done automatically. Does anyone know of a convenient way to encrypt the data on a USB drive?

**Update**: I am using Windows Vista, although I would prefer a cross-platform solution.

Comment: What OS and version are you using? The higher editions of Vista and Windows 7 come with Bitlocker drive encryption built-in.

Comment: Related question (though not answered yet): http://superuser.com/questions/48084/looking-for-a-usb-thumbdrive-flash-drive-encryption-solution-not-truecrypt

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/62022/how-to-add-password-in-a-usb-stick and http://superuser.com/questions/48084/looking-for-a-usb-thumbdrive-flash-drive-encryption-solution-not-truecrypt

Comment: Bitlocker on Vista does not support removeable drives like USB keys. Bitlocker-to-go on Windows 7 does, however. Yo ucan also use policies to detemine whether USB media can be used at all, or control them to be read only or allow writing, depending on whether or not they hav ebeen encrypted (eg do not allow writing to a non-encrypted removeable drive)

Answer (score 22):

try [truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) it suits usb sticks really well. you can encrypt the whole drive or just certain folders. and it's cross platform

from their homepage:

> Free open-source disk encryption
>   software for Windows 7/Vista/XP, Mac
>   OS X, and Linux
>
> Main Features:
>
> - Creates a virtual encrypted disk within a file and mounts it as a real
>     disk.
> - Encrypts an entire partition or storage device such as USB flash drive
>     or hard drive.
> - Encrypts a partition or drive where Windows is installed (pre-boot
>     authentication).
> - Encryption is automatic, real-time (on-the-fly) and transparent.
> - Parallelization and pipelining allow data to be read and written as fast as
>     if the drive was not encrypted.
> - Provides plausible deniability, in case an adversary forces you to reveal
>     the password:
>
>   Hidden volume (steganography) and
>     hidden operating system.
> - Encryption algorithms: AES-256, Serpent, and Twofish. Mode of
>     operation: XTS.

Answer (score 7):

I use [truecrypt](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/encrypt-your-usb-stick-with-truecrypt-60/)

Creates a encryptred folder and then all you do is drag the files into the folder

Comment: The problem with TrueCrypt is the unmounting. You first have to unmount the TrueCrypt volume, and then eject the USB stick (to flush the write cache).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a commercial product like [PGP whole disk encryption](http://www.pgp.com/products/wholediskencryption/index.html) or something like [truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) that's more cross-platform compatible? 
Or perhaps you're looking for something that automatically mounts the crypto drive when you insert an encrypted USB stick that has a crypto volume on it? (or tries to, if it has true random data)

Answer (score 0):

You could make an encrypted disk image on it and put your files in that or get an ironkey.

Comment: This seeems like it should be a comment rather then an answer.