# Protecting data on USB

Tags: usb-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to encrypt an USB stick?](https://superuser.com/questions/75177/how-to-encrypt-an-usb-stick)

I have a lot of usb's that I frequently carry around with me, and equally frequently lose around me. Since some of the data on them I do not wish to be made public (*it is nothing critical - just some personal documents, excel sheets and such that I don't want people to read if I can help it in some way - no direct damage occurs if they do get a hold of them, however, but still...)* I was wondering what would be the easiest way to protect them on an usb stick.

I was wishfully thinking - is there some way to encrypt your data on an usb, then when you insert the usb some program asks you for a password, after which all your files seem "normal". If someone else inserts the usb into his/her computer and either does not start the program or enters the wrong password, then all he sees of the contents of the files as gibberish.

Is there such a thing? If not, what would you suggest for something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/75177/how-to-encrypt-an-usb-stick (and all the questions listed there)

Comment: Don't lose your USB flash drive :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use encryption software for you USB flash drive.  [This](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is one that I found, but I'm sure there are plenty other out there.

Comment: Yes, I was about to suggest TrueCrypt too.

But there are a lot of other free ones available online too. Do a little searching.

TrueCrypt is open-source, however, so use that.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [post](http://lifehacker.com/391555/best-free-ways-to-protect-your-private-files), it recommends some free apps to protect your information.