# What do I need to use to encrypt my USB hard disk?

Tags: ubuntu, security, ubuntu-10.04, encryption, disk-encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to encrypt an USB stick?](https://superuser.com/questions/75177/how-to-encrypt-an-usb-stick)

I want to encrypt my USB hard disk. And I want to do it with open source software. And
I want to use only password for decryption. And I want to decrypt it using an Ubuntu 10.04 LiveCD, with no Internet-connection. And I don't want solutions using, for example, DES with 56 bit. At least AES 256 bit, please!

What is the solution?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [LUKS](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_dm_crypt_luks) for that. Steps 5 through 7 are the important ones.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org).

Comment: "i want to decrypt it using an Ubuntu 10.04 LiveCD, with no internet-connection."

Comment: You can have the program on the HDD (obviously not encrypting that part of the drive.)

Comment: "i want to decrypt it using an Ubuntu 10.04 LiveCD, with no internet-connection." -> plus....i can't even download truecrypt, because the tar.gz file, that contains the sources is corrupt, at least when i want to download it from truecrypt.org..... -> but thank you!