# What are effective ways to encrypt a USB drive on Windows

Tags: windows, security, encryption, usb-storage, disk-encryption

I'm re-asking this question because [the existing question is 9 years old](https://superuser.com/questions/75177/how-to-encrypt-an-usb-stick) and I assume there's been improvement since then.

I have a portable USB drive and if I lose it I don't want someone else then accessing my source files. So what are good, and rock solid methods to encrypt the drive?

On Windows (latest version).

Comment: TrueCrypt still holds high even today, but BitLocker is a good alternative. Just make sure you store the encryption key somewhere else, eg on your pc's TPM

Comment: I changed program to methods to allow the question to be relevant for this site as looking for software recommendations is not allowed. +1.

Comment: Without an operating system I am voting to close this question as requiring additional details

Comment: Should remove "best" from the title as this is opinion-based now.

Comment: @Destroy666 - done. thank (good advice).

Answer (score 0):

While VeraCrypt is still highly regarded, if you plan to *share* the USB with others, or *use it on another machine*, consider using Zip compression with [AES-256 encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). This has the advantage of being usable without additional software in many operating systems, or portable 7-Zip could be included on the USB (Windows version of 7-zip runs well on Linux, too, under wine, and there's a Mac version, as well). Within the same archive can be sub-archives with different passwords, allowing one to share *some* data but not all.

Of course, it depends on the value of the information to a third party. One casually finding a lost USB, or even a determined thief, likely cannot break AES-256. A state agency might make the effort to try, if they believe the data might be valuable or a threat.

Comment: TrueCrypt isn’t highly recommended. Since it’s no longer maintained or secure, it’s community replacement, is actually Veracrypt.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks... that was a moment's forgetfulness, and is corrected.

Comment: It's all my source code, in the solution folders, that I edit, run, push to GitHub, etc. So a zip file is not a good solution. thanks

Comment: What about BitLocker?

Comment: @DavidThielen If you want to have direct access to the contained files, VeraCrypt would be the way to go. But be aware that USB thumb drives are usually equipped with the cheapest flash memory available on the market. Therefore IMHO an external SSD would be more suitable if you want to store important data on it and directly work on the drive (not just use it as backup).

Comment: One *caveat* about *long-term storage* on flash, SSD and NVMe: "data stored on a HDD will degrade far more slowly than data stored on a SSD that uses NAND flash memory," due to charge leakage. https://www.ontrack.com/en-us/blog/hdds-vs-ssds If the data is refreshed every few months, that should not be a problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not BitLocker?

Comment: 1. BitlLocker is proprietary, an not available on all Windows platforms, much less other OS. 2. VeraCrypt has been audited: https://ostif.org/the-veracrypt-audit-results/  See also https://www.comparitech.com/blog/information-security/disk-encryption-software/